# Refresh Page only time

Tags: html, webbrowser-control, meta-tags

I write a meta tag for refreshing web page. Now i want to refresh a page only one time.
What is the code for refreshing page only one time. Please help me to fix the problem...

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Why do you need to only refresh the page once?

Answer (score 1):

Using javascript you could set a cookie with a "`refreshed`" variable in it and check if it's set, if not then refresh the page. Of course  this involves quite a lot of code for setting and reading from the cookie plus the function to be called when you reload.

My approach would be url vars, then again it's php not meta tags, it would be something like this:

```
<?php 
    if($_GET['r'] != 1) header('refresh: 0; url=/index.php?r=1');
?>
```

Which reloads the page setting a variable in the url ,in this case `r` for refreshed, as true.
So the next time it loads it will not reload . It works, it's just one line of code and it will save you some coding time and get the job done.

Update: (User wanted it in asp)

Should work but I haven't tried it nor can I try it at the moment (I'm at the airport)

```
<%
    dim refreshOnce
    refreshOnce = request.querystring("r")

    if refreshOnce <> 1 then  Response.AddHeader "Refresh", "0;URL=/index.php?r=1"
%>
```

Comment: Thanks and its fine, but i am working in asp.net in what way i write the code in .aspx page. Please help me..

Comment: I don't work with asp but a little research helped me translate the code to the one shown up now, haven't tried it though.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript solution, using a form field to store the state:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script language="javascript">
      function init() {
        var form = document.getElementById('theform');
        var input = form.refreshed;
        function reload() {
          location.reload(false);
        }
        function isRefreshed() {
          return !!input.value;
        }
        function doDisplay() {
          var el = document.getElementById(isRefreshed() ? 'two' : 'one');
          el.style.display = 'block';
        }
        function conditionalRefresh() {
          if (!isRefreshed()) {
            input.value = 'true';
            setTimeout(reload, 1000);
          }
        }
        doDisplay();
        conditionalRefresh();
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="init();">
    <form id="theform">
      <input type="hidden" name="refreshed" />
    </form>
    <div id="one" style="display: none;">
      one
    </div>
    <div id="two" style="display: none;">
      two
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```